# Get same vicinity bounds from Google Maps Api v3 as google.com/maps delivers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In short I would like to get the same area as Google Maps sets for a given vicinity (sublocality), example `Ribersborg, Malmö` below:

[image]

What I have been able to do is get the north east LatLng and south west LatLng from the viewport-object. These values are the same as the bounds object that I can get from the [geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).

From these values I can get a nice rectangle like below but I would like to have it printed exactly like it is on Google Maps. Is this possible in the current API?

[image]

Current code:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

if (place.geometry.viewport) {

    var ne = place.geometry.viewport.getNorthEast(); // LatLng of the north-east corner
    var sw = place.geometry.viewport.getSouthWest(); // LatLng of the south-west corder
    var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(), sw.lng());
    var se = new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat(), ne.lng());

    var rectangleCoords = [
        { lat: ne.lat(), lng: ne.lng() },
        { lat: nw.lat(), lng: nw.lng() },
        { lat: sw.lat(), lng: sw.lng() },
        { lat: se.lat(), lng: se.lng() }
    ];

    var rectangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: rectangleCoords,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    rectangle.setMap(map);
}

//place.vicinity is 'Ribersborg'
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': place.vicinity },
    function (results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            //results[0].geometry.bounds is the same as place.geometry.viewport (and results[0].geometry.viewport)
        }
    });
```

Comment: Google's APIs don't (currently) provide the polygon's coordinates.  There is a (long) outstanding feature request for that information to be provided.  ([feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109))

Comment: @geocodezip Thank you for your answer!

Comment: To the person voting down, please motivate why, otherwise it is hard to write a better question the next time.